# Как изменить стиль элемента, при наведении на другой? (CSS)

Tags: css, html5, css3, меню, hover

Я просмотрел похожие вопросы и не нашел ответа на свой. В общем, есть горизонтальное меню и подменю, не могу вывести подменю при наведении на пункт горизонтального меню. Пытался делать через JS(сам не разбираюсь, брал код из ответов и адаптировал под свои id и class'ы), но не получилось. JS в браузере включен, пользуюсь браузером Google Chrome. Не удивляйтесь комментариям с пробелами в коде, это я так убрал пробелы между li со свойством display: inline-block. Вот сам код:`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <style>
    * {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .tmenu {
 width: 100%;
    }
    .innertmenu {
 width: 1200px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #333333;
 margin: auto;
    }
    .tmenuul {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
    }
    .tmenuli {
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: firasansbold;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
    }
    .tmenuli:hover {
 background-color: #666666;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
    }
    #hiddenmenu {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 200px;
 display: none;
    }
    .hiddenmenuli {
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: firasansbold;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #333333;
    }
    .hiddenmenuli:hover {
 background-color: #666666;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
    }
    #cat:hover + #hiddenmenu {
 display: block;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="tmenu">
   <div class="innertmenu">
   <ul class="tmenuul">
    <a href="#"><li class="tmenuli">Главная</li></a><!--
    --><a href="#"><li id="cat" class="tmenuli">Категории</li></a><!--
    --><ul id="hiddenmenu"><!--
     --><a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #1</li></a><!--
     --><a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #2</li></a><!--
     --><a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #3</li></a><!--
     --><a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #4</li></a><!--
    --></ul><!--
    --><a href="#"><li class="tmenuli">Лучшее</li></a><!--
    --><a href="#"><li class="tmenuli">Контакты</li></a>
   </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Вариант номер 2, учтён комментарий от soledar10(вёрстка немного поехала, но не в этом суть):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Test.ru</title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
* {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
.tmenu {
 width: 100%;
}
.innertmenu {
 width: 1200px;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: #333333;
 margin: auto;
}
.tmenuul {
 list-style-type: none;
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
}
.tmenuli {
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: firasansbold;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: white;
 display: inline-block;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}
.tmenuli:hover {
 background-color: #666666;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
}
#hiddenmenu {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: 200px;
 display: none;
}
.hiddenmenuli {
 width: 200px;
 height: 50px;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: firasansbold;
 font-size: 24px;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #333333;
}
.hiddenmenuli:hover {
 background-color: #666666;
 transition: 0.5s ease;
}
.tmenuul > #cat:hover > #hiddenmenu {
 display: block;
}
</style>
<div class="tmenu">
   <div class="innertmenu">
   <ul class="tmenuul">
    <a href="#"><li class="tmenuli">Главная</li></a><!--
    --><a href="#"><li id="cat" class="tmenuli">Категории</li></a><!--
    --><ul id="hiddenmenu"><!--
     --><a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #1</li></a><!--
     --><a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #2</li></a><!--
     --><a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #3</li></a><!--
     --><a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #4</li></a><!--
    --></ul><!--
    --><a href="#"><li class="tmenuli">Лучшее</li></a><!--
    --><a href="#"><li class="tmenuli">Контакты</li></a>
   </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Оформите свой код с помощью утилиты "фрагмент кода."

Comment: _это я так убрал пробелы между li_ - а есть смысл это делать?

Comment: @kiLLro, оформил

Comment: @AGS17 , есть. Я читал, что li ведут себя как буквы, то есть пробелы между li которые расположены в ряд происходят из-за как минимум одного пробела в коде(остальные не считаются, как и с буквами в тексте). Я поставил комментарии, тем самым, не давая появится пробелу между элементами li.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/rmmtn1hz/

Comment: @Trounee а можно пруф линку на данную литературу?

Comment: @AGS17 , я хз тут можно оставлять ссылки или нет(15 мин назад зарегался ради этого вопроса), поэтому просто набери в гугле: "как убрать пробелы между li" и на первом сайте, который выдаст гугл, будет статейка об этом. Статья называется: "Загадочные отступы между инлайн-элементами"

Comment: @soledar10 , посмотри, пожалуйста, я добавил второй вариант, где в соответствующие блоки добавил свойства, как по ссылке. Вёрстка поехала, но все еще не работает. Не подскажешь, где я накосячил?

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить такой вариант, можно украшать и украшать.

```css
  *{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }

  ul{
    list-style: none;
  }

  li{
    color: white;
    background-color: grey;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  li:hover, .drop_menu li:hover{
    background-color: pink;
  }

  .drop_menu{
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  li:hover .drop_menu{
    display: block;
  }

  .drop_menu li{
    float: none;
    display: block;
    background-color: #3d3d3d;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>menu</title>

</head>
<body>

  <ul>
    <li>Первый</li>
    <li>Второй
      <ul class='drop_menu'>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Третий</li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Вот Ваш пример полностью переделанный

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Test</title>
  <style>
  * {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  body{
    font-family: firasansbold;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: white;
    background-color: gray
  }
  a {
    width: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;
  }
  a:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .tmenu {
    width: 1200px;
    background-color: #333333;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 50px;
  }
  .tmenuli {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
  }
  #hiddenmenu {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
  }
  .hiddenmenuli {
    min-width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #333333;
  }
  .hiddenmenuli:hover {
    background-color: #666666;
    transition: background 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }
  #cat:hover #hiddenmenu {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="tmenu">
    <div class="innertmenu">
      <ul class="tmenuul">
        <li class="tmenuli"><a href="#">Главная</a></li>
        <li id="cat" class="tmenuli"><a href="#">Категории</a>
          <ul id="hiddenmenu">
            <li class="hiddenmenuli"><a href="#">Категория #1</a></li>
            <li class="hiddenmenuli"><a href="#">Категория #2</a></li>
            <li class="hiddenmenuli"><a href="#">Категория #3</a></li>
            <li class="hiddenmenuli"><a href="#">Категория #4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="tmenuli"><a href="#">Лучшее</a></li>
        <li class="tmenuli"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Мне кажется, что что-то в моем коде перекрывает этот блок с пунктом меню li и не дает выполниться псевдоэлементу hover. Просто я сделал все в точности как у вас, исключая цвет, размер и отступы(те же свойства задал, float, position, display), но все равно не работает. Если не сложно, подскажите, есть ли в моем коде что-нибудь "перекрывающее" блок, при наведении на который должны появиться подпункты? Я лишь скопировал фрагмент с меню сюда, а на деле, на странице еще много всего, поэтому сложно будет все переделывать сначала.

Comment: У Вас другая проблема, дело в том что по правилам css управлять можно только объектами которые являются детьми. А вы закрыли свой Li, перенесите и все сработает

Comment: [код]<a href="#"><li id="cat" class="tmenuli">Категории</a>
            <ul id="hiddenmenu">
              <a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #1</li></a>
              <a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #2</li></a>
              <a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #3</li></a>
              <a href="#"><li class="hiddenmenuli">Категория #4</li></a>
            </ul>
          </li>[код]

Answer (score 0):

1 - Ссылки должны находиться внутри списка.

```
 <ul>
     <li><a href="#link1">Ссылка 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#link2">Ссылка 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#link3">Ссылка 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

2 - Список может иметь вложенный список, что в нашем случае и будет являться подменю. Чистый CSS без JS. Пример:

CSS разметка:

```css
.menu li{
    list-style: none; /*Убирам маркеры списка */
    float: left; /*Превращаем список в строчку*/
    margin-left: 10px; /*Откступы влево*/
}
.menu li:first-child{
    /* Псевдокласс :first-child позволяет задать первому элементу отдельные стили. В нашем случае - это обнуление отступов */
    margin-left: 0;
}
.menu li ul{
    /* Скрываем вложенный список. Лучше это делать другими способами, но в нашем случае данный вариант будет наглядней.*/
    display: none;
    
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
.menu li:hover ul{
    /* Если пунк меню имеет вложеный список, то он отобразится. */
    display: block;
}
/*Стилизуем наше подменю*/
/* Следите внимательно за последовательностью - .menu li ul li
.menu - это наш главный список > далее в нем содержатся li > в этом списке вложен другой ul и в нем также присутствуюют > li
*/
.menu li ul li{
    float: none; 
    padding-top: 10px;
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
         <li>
             <a href="#link1">Ссылка 1</a>
             <ul>
                 <li><a href="#sub_link1">Ссылка подменю 1</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#sub_link2">Ссылка подменю 2</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#sub_link2">Ссылка подменю 2</a></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#link2">Ссылка 2</a></li>
         <li><a href="#link3">Ссылка 3</a></li>
</ul>
```